# How to execute stored procedure and get return result in MVC/EF/LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

Could any one guide me on how to execute a SQL Server stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC / EF
application and get results back?

**SQL Server stored procedure**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure2 AS
     declare @parameter2 int
     SET @parameter2 = 4

     RETURN @parameter2
```

**MVC code**

```
 private readonly TestDatastoreContext _context = new TestDatastoreContext();

 public ViewResult Index(string id)
 {
        ViewData["EnvironmentId"] = id;

        using (_context)
        {
            _context.Database.Connection.Open();
            var command = _context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "dbo.StoredProcedure2";
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var test = (command.ExecuteScalar());
        }

        var bigView = new BigViewModel
        {
            VersionsModel = _context.Versions.ToList(),
            EnvironmentViewModel = _context.Environments.ToList(),
        };

        return View(model: bigView);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do, what it actually does and what you have tried to explain and annihilate those differences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is this: you're returning the value from the stored procedure (using `RETURN @paramter2`), but your .NET code is trying to read a result set; something that would be "returned" by using a `SELECT .....` statement inside the stored procedure

So change your stored procedure to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure2 AS
     declare @parameter2 int
     SET @parameter2 = 4

     SELECT @parameter2
```

and then your .NET code should work just fine.

The `RETURN` statement should be used for **status codes** only and it can return `INT` values only. If you want to use that, you'll have to define a `SqlParameter` for your stored procedure with a `Direction.ReturnValue`

Answer (score 4):

Check this official doc on how to map the `Stored Procedure` to your Context:

[Stored Procedures in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx)

After the mapping you'll be able to call the `Stored Procedure` this way:

```
var val = _context.StoredProcedure2();
```

Comment: That will only work if using an EDMX file.  It won't work with code first, which the asker hasn't said which version he's using.

Comment: I posted a link which has nice utility to work with code first.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to simply do this:

```
MyReturnEntity ret = context.Database
         .SqlQuery<MyReturnEntity>("exec myStoredProc ?, ?", param1, parm2);
```

Comment: it doesn't work:   "Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '?'."

Comment: @Teo He's referring to the name of the parameters in the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:
https://github.com/mrmmins/C-StoreProcedureModelBinding

Returns the values as a List, you only need create a simple class with the names and values types, like:

```
var productos = DataReaderT.ReadStoredProceadures<MyCustomModel>(myDbEntityInstance, "dbo.MySPName", _generic);
```

and MyCumtomModel class is something like:

```
public int id {get; set;}
public int salary {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
public string school {get; set;}
```

and generic like:

```
List<Generic> _generic = = new List<Generic>
                          {
                              new Generic
                                  {
                                      Key = "@phase", Type = SqlDbType.Int, Value = "207"
                                  }
                          }
                      };
```

And now, your `products` has the options like: `products.First()`, `products.Count()`, `foreach` etc.